# Python pyshp reads some field values as None

Tags: python, shapefile, python-2.7, pyshp

Reading the records of `AL082017_pts.shp` in a [recent hurricane path file](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/best_track/al082017_best_track.zip) with [pyshp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp) results in a lot of `None`.

Here's the first record:

```
sf = shapefile.Reader('AL082017_pts.shp')
print sf.record(0)
```

Output:

```
['GENESIS014', None, None, '08', None, '0600', None, 'al', None, 'DB', None, None, None, None]
```

The correct field values, as can be seen in the dbf, are:

```
GENESIS014  2017080206  2017    08  2   0600    1012    al  8   DB  20  0   9.5 -13
```

**It seems that the non-string fields are printed as `None`. How can I read these values correctly?**

Here's the output of `sf.fields`:

```
[('DeletionFlag', 'C', 1, 0), ['STORMNAME', 'C', 50, 0], ['DTG', 'F', 50, 0], ['YEAR', 'F', 50, 0], ['MONTH', 'C', 50, 0], ['DAY', 'F', 50, 0], ['HHMM', 'C', 50, 0], ['MSLP', 'F', 50, 0], ['BASIN', 'C', 50, 0], ['STORMNUM', 'F', 50, 0], ['STORMTYPE', 'C', 50, 0], ['INTENSITY', 'F', 50, 0], ['SS', 'F', 50, 0], ['LAT', 'F', 50, 0], ['LON', 'F', 50, 0]]
```

Comment: This is odd. I don't have any problems reading the shapefile you work with. What's your `pyshp` version? Mine is `shapefile.__version__
'1.2.3'`

Comment: I get the same `None`'s with `shapefile.__version__` '1.2.11'. No problem reading the shapefiles with `fiona`.

Comment: Works fine in 1.2.10 (Python 3, Linux). Sounds like a case for a regression bug report.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I'm on 1.2.11 like Luke. Can confirm, stepping back to 1.2.3 solves the problem. Seems like a regression ... I opened an issue on https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp/issues/108

Comment: Ha. Just tested on 1.2.11 (downloaded a separate version) and also getting a bunch of `None` like Luke and Martin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for submitting the issue on GitHub @Martin Burch.

The issue was with the numeric fields as suspected, but was also related to this specific shapefile which had a minor error in it (the reason other libs were able to read it correctly was probably that they were more lenient with handling errors like that).

Pyshp usually reads numeric fields correctly, but in this case it failed because the driver that wrote the shapefile wrote int fields "incorrectly" as floats, that is with the ".0" at the end. The numeric fields that fail are all defined as ints (decimal=0), so pyshp tries to convert the string to int, but calling int on a float string doesn't work.

The reason this was not an issue prior to v1.2.11 was due to an attempt in v1.2.11 to root out errors in the reading of field types and make it more robust. In doing so it was made a lot stricter in the expected values, assuming perfectly written shapefiles, which is probably too stringent.

So the answer to solving this problem is to revert back to an earlier version as mentioned, or wait for release 1.2.12 shortly or the upcoming major version 2.0.0. These versions will be backwards compatible with the more lenient approach of v1.2.10, and handle minor data type errors in shapefiles by adding forced conversion.

**Update:**

Version 1.2.12 which fixes this issue is [now up on PyPI.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp)